# Characterizing a neural action potential in space and time

Tags: electromagnetism

Action potentials are perturbations in the transmembrane potential of a neuron that propagate from one end to the other. Hence, they are functions of both space and time:

1. By placing an electrode at a given location, one can measure how the action potential behaves at that location as a function of time.
2. By placing multiple electrodes along the neuron, one can measure, at one instance in time, what the action potential looks like along the length of the neuron.

The duration of an action potential is approximately 3 ms. This is the temporal span over which a given location experiences a change in membrane potential due to the action potential. Say $\Phi(t)$ gives the transmembrane voltage over time at one location. If we assume a constant conduction velocity of $v$ m/s, intuitively, I believe the "shape" of $\Phi(t)$ and the "shape" of $\Phi(x)$ - the transmembrane voltage as a function of space - should be the same. Mathematically, if we assume a constant conduction velocity, how can we convert the function of time $\Phi(t)$ to a function of space $\Phi(x)$? Does the duration of the signal (3 ms in this example) matter (does it affect the resulting "shape" of $\Phi(x)$?

[image: Schematic of an action potential.]

Answer (score 1):

So what you are describing, if I understand this correctly is a wave, which one can express as $\Phi(x-vt)$ [or $\Phi'(x/v-t)$ depending on your definition]. It is the same shape, shifted in time. If you measure at one point (say at $x=0$) then you will get $\Phi(-vt)$ [or $\Phi'(-t)$]. On the other hand, if you measure along the neuron at a fixed time (say $t=0$), you'll get $\Phi(x)$ [or $\Phi'(x/v)$].

Note the change in the sign of the argument. It implies that the function in space (along the neuron) is the reversed version of the function in time.

Comment: Interesting, thanks so much! For some reason, I couldn't wrap my head around the fact that the conduction velocity affects the observed signal both at a given location and at a given instance in time... Over time for a given location, the signal is reversed because it is "passing through the location," and the start of the neuron is going to experience what happened last in time when the latter part of the neuron is experiencing what happened first.

Answer (score 0):

By substitution of variables Φ(x)=Φ(vt) and Φ(x/v)=Φ(t)

The manner in which you can extract the constant v or 1/v from the equation ultimately depends upon the properties of the formula, which are in a black box.

Since the potential starts from a resting potential and returns to a resting potential for each cycle, it is probably appropriate to approximate the cycle as a trig function such as sine or cosine tweaked by a somewhat tricky set of parameters.

This should make it possible to use trig identities to evaluate your questions.